# Adding text to image not in the right position Swift

Tags: swift, image, text

I use this code to add text from textview to Image

```
func textToImage(drawText: NSString, inImage: UIImage, atPoint: CGPoint) -> UIImage{

// Setup the font specific variables
var textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
var textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 12)!

// Setup the image context using the passed image
let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inImage.size, false, scale)

// Setup the font attributes that will be later used to dictate how the text should be drawn
let textFontAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
]

// Put the image into a rectangle as large as the original image
inImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height))

// Create a point within the space that is as bit as the image
var rect = CGRectMake(atPoint.x, atPoint.y, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)

// Draw the text into an image
drawText.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

// Create a new image out of the images we have created
var newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

// End the context now that we have the image we need
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//Pass the image back up to the caller
return newImage

}
```

I download image from server, and add text for this. I already resize the image before I add text for that to fit the device i am using, in this case is Iphone 6s, 375*667

When I add text from textView which is red in the picture to my image, it isn't in the right position. It is always pushed to the right without reason.

Does anyone know about this problem ? 
Thank you very much !!!
[image: When I type text view]

[image: The result]

Comment: What is the value of the atPoint argument you pass when calling this function?

Comment: I use touch began and touch move to get current position of the textView ??? Do you have this issue before?

Comment: I haven't encountered this issue, just trying to help you debug it. If you are using a gesture recogniser to place the text, have you logged the position according to the gesture recogniser and compared that with the position that your text ultimately appears at?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a square. If you set both the X and Y to 0, it won't place the middle of the square to the x: 0 and y: 0. It will place the top left of that square to that coordinate. Your issue is that when you call your function, it's placing the top left of the text to the point of where you tapped. You have to minus half of the texts width for the X and half of the texts height for the Y. It should look something like this:

```
func textToImage(drawText: "Hello, inImage: ***YOUR_IMAGE***, atPoint: CGPoint(x: point.x - (text.frame.width / 2), y: point.y - (text.frame.height / 2))
```